# How to write file from within php - Permission denied

Tags: php, permissions

Sorry to ask a basic question, but I cannot find the answer.  I am trying to write to a file from within PHP but it fails with Permission denied, and I don't know why.
My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>File test</title>

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

echo 'Current script owner: ' . get_current_user();
echo '<br>WhoAmI: '. shell_exec( 'whoami' );
echo '<br>cwd: '.getcwd();
$plist = fopen("plist.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($plist, 'some text');
fclose($plist);
?>
```

This is the output I see

```
Current script owner: mick
WhoAmI: www-data
cwd: /home/mick/Documents/www/test
Warning: fopen(plist.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/mick/Documents/www/test/fileTest.php on line 13
Unable to open file!
```

My user (mick) obviously owns the directory I am trying to write to and www-data is a member of the 'mick' group. I have also set the directory to 777 to try to get it to work but still get the error.  What have I missed here?

Comment: Dude, run `ls -la /home/mick/Documents/www/test`.

Comment: What is current file path and what is path for text file ?

Comment: That returns -rw-r--r--  1 mick mick  374 Apr  1 15:33 fileTest.php

Comment: The code is in /home/mick/Documents/www/test/  and I assume it should create the txt file in the same directory

Answer (score 1):

You need give permission for *www-data* user. You can do it by running these commands:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /home/mick/Documents/www/test
sudo chmod 777 /home/mick/Documents/www/test
```

The above code gives full access for user *www-data* to the directory.

Or add w+ inner fopen. It will create the file if doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes it is apache.  I have just tried your suggestion and it makes no difference, still get the same error.

Comment: OK I think I have it now.  I had create the text file at some point, with owner 'mick' and I assumed that I should be able to write to it.  At the time I hadn't realised that it would write as www-data.  It works now.  Thanks for your help.